# How to calculate logic gates power in microwatts in Matlab?

Tags: power, digital-logic, simulation, matlab

I am designing a logic gates sequential circuit in Matlab2014 Simulink using logic gates and I am giving Pulse and Constant at the input of the circuit but I cannot measure current and voltage at the output of the circuit. How can I measure power at the output and calculate in microwatts in Matlab Simulink?

Comment: Are you using ideal logic gates or specific implementations? (e.g. 74LS-whatever)

Answer (score 1):

You need to split out for each logic pack (ie is it a single, dual, quad..)

1. Its quiescent current draw => power. Refer to datasheet
2. Its output current. Refer to data sheet of the load/input impedance
3. Any switching losses stated

If you want todo it on a per gate/package basis in simulink may I advise you to make a subsystem per package and one of the outputs is a constant+dynamic power draw. All such output can be put into a sigma block

Comment: Thanks for answers but I used Power for power calculating but Output from gates was single and Power inputs are two [Current, Voltage] and its outputs are two P[Power] and Q[Variance], power 1st o/p is 1.5 and second 0.0096 etc and variance is 0. Is my answer right or I miss something. Please answer me.